# Do we need the Communication tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have 56 questions tagged [communication](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication).  This strikes me as a meta-tag which has no intrinsic merit.

Most of the questions are also tagged with a specific form of communication: [serial](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serial), [ethernet](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethernet), [wireless](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless) etc.

Do we need [communication](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication)? or should it be expunged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say there is a subset of questions where the question does warrant a generic communication tag (e.g. [What should I use for wireless communication between an Arduino and a Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51663/what-should-i-use-for-wireless-communication-between-an-arduino-and-a-raspberry)). In this case the more specific tags are not appropriate or limit potential answers uneccesarily.

The majority of questions are posted by users who are new to the site, the Pi and electronics, and who may not have the knowledge to better formulate or tag their question. Obviously others can edit the tags in the event a more specific tag is appropriate, but as the previous example makes clear there may be no better tag, and this could lead to two problems a user giving up because they do not know how  to tag their question, or more likely, the user choosing the most generic tag such as Pi foundation (see discussion here [What should we do to [raspberry-pi-foundation]?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/780/what-should-we-do-to-raspberry-pi-foundation)).

Comment: Point taken, I can't argue with that.  Perhaps then the tag guidance, currently none, could be created to help here.

Comment: Why don't you give it a shot, or do you not have enough rep? Though I am not sure it will help with the new user issue - it can at times seem like trying to empty a lake with a spoon.

Comment: I'll suggest something.  I know not all new users actually read the tag wikis but many do.